# Dragon Strike Pull not triggering traps

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any reason why Jarvan IV's Dragon Strike to his Demacian Standard wouldn't trigger traps such as Teemo's mushrooms or Nidalee's traps.

I ask because I was playing a game as Teemo this weekend, and watched a J4 get pulled through my shroom to his Standard and not trigger it. It was not a new Shroom (it was 
certainly active) and was not disabled due to Sweeping Lens or similar.

I've added an image to show approximately how it happened. Could it be that the trap wasn't triggered due to terrain effects? I find it hard to believe, but does anyone else have any ideas.

[image: J4 vs Mushroom]

I've had a look at the wiki, and I can't find any reference that suggests that Dragon Strike pull doesn't trigger traps. Can anyone replicate this behavior?

Comment: My bet is that J4's champion model intersected with the mushroom, but his hitbox did not.

Comment: It is most likely a bug/hitbox problem. The descritpion of the skill clearly says "pull" wich usually triggers traps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must have been a bug, probably with the hitbox. A Dash will **Always** trigger Trap effects. Even Abilities like Unstoppable force and Assault and Battery. Usually the Damage stats instantly while the Crowd Control effect starts after the caster has reached his destination.

The only Way to avoid Traps while in a dash is becoming untargetable (Maokai, Zed, Fizz) otherwise the trap should be triggered.

Comment: It actually is a bug. If the targets moves too fast over the shroom/trap, it won't collide. There are similar problems with Vaynes E.